# Storing a username on sign up only displays after page refresh (Firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to React and Firebase, and I've been trying to solve this small User Sign-Up problem **all day**. Hopefully someone can help me out, *I'd be so grateful*

I am making a twitter-like blog site with react and Firebase, and am currently using Firebase's auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword() method to register a new user, with a username. This is how I'm doing it:

```js
  import { auth } from '../firebase';

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
      .then((result) => {
        result.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: data.username,
        });
        setUserError(!userError);
        window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', data.email);
        setRedirect(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setUserError(!userError);
        setAlertMsg(error.message);
      });
  };
```

After the user submits the form, they are redirected to the main page, which I then set the page to their current username. I'm setting the username by setting a state for it, and then passing it as a prop to all my pages.

```js
const Main = ({SignOut}) => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('')


  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserName = () => {
      auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        setUserName(user.displayName)
        console.log('Current userName is: ', user.displayName);
      });
    }
    getUserName() 
  }, [])
  
    return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Navbar userName={userName} SignOut={SignOut} />
            <Tweets userName={userName} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/profile">
            <Navbar userName={userName} SignOut={SignOut} />
            <Profile setUserName={setUserName} userName={userName} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Almost everything works perfectly, however their username only shows up if they log out and log back in.
Any help would be awesome!

**EDIT**

Here is my App Component. I moved the useEffect event here, however, I am still experiencing the same thing.

```js
function App() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserName = () => {
      auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        setUserName(user.displayName);
        console.log('Current userName is: ', user.displayName);
      });
    };
    getUserName();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {user ? (
        <Main userName={userName} setUserName={setUserName} SignOut={SignOut} />
      ) : (
        <Register />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's because the function you pass to `onAuthStateChanged` runs *when the user logs in our out*. You need to set up that listener before the users logs in for the first time, so if `<Main>` is only rendered for a user that is already logged in, that's too late. Move setting up the listener to your `<App>` component.

Comment: I though that would work, but I'm still encountering the same bug.
I posted my App.js so you can see how I'm using it.
Thanks so much

Comment: Right, so when is the console.log called, and what does it say? Note that signing out might cause an error with your current code, since `user` will be `null`.

Comment: Right right. It says null when a user signs up for the first time. There is no error when users log out. Sorry I'm such a noob with all of this.
I just want to avoid creating a new state just to solve this one small bug.

Comment: Wait, signing up is different from logging in. That handler runs when the user logs in/out. Just to make sure we're on the same page. There's three possible states: 1) not being registered yet, 2) being registered but not logged in, and 3) being logged in. The client-side cannot distinguish between 1&2 obviously.

Comment: Definitely. But after a new user signs up for the first time, they will automatically be redirected to the main page and sign in with the account that they just created. So I'm just not sure why it says `null` for the first time.

Comment: How do they sign in? Are you using a popup? Or is it a form in a component? If so, which one? What is the exact timeline of form submission, console logs, etc.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225625/discussion-between-ryan-roberts-and-chris-g).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a super noob bug that I was experiencing, but instead of using useEffect to set the username, I just passed my setUserName state to my sign up component, and did away with useEffect entirely.
This fixed everything.

```js
  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
      .then((result) => {
        result.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: data.username,
        });
        // This is the state i was missing.
        setUserName(data.username);
        setUserError(!userError);
        window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', data.email);
        setRedirect(true);
      })
```